# How would you compare a dictionary containing unhashable ojects?

Tags: python-3.x

Per title. I have 2 dicts, and they both contain lists:

```
d1 = {'AES': [256], 'Blowfish': [224, 448]} 
d2 = {'AES': [128, 192, 256], 'Blowfish': [112, 224, 448], 'DES': [56]}
```

The ideal results should be something clear and easy to work with; the function output format is dictated to be a tuple of (str, int), but I am more focused on how to compare them and obtain an easily utilized result.

For the record, the desired result should indicate that the only supported encryption formats above are AES 256 and Blowfish 224 and Blowfish 448

I feel I should add that my python version is 3.6.8

Addendum: I feel that I haven't been very clear, my apologies. The function I'm working on will take the results of the comparison and select the key, value pair that has the greatest value (essentially, it selects the cryptosystem to use based on key length). It outputs that selection as a tuple, which in this case is (Blowfish, 448). I'm just more interested in the comparison part, but I feel as if my lack of clarity is not good, so once again, my apologies.

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes it is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the intersection of the keys first. You can do that with:

```
set(d1) & set(d2)
```

Then for each of the saved keys, you can find the intersection of the lists. Allthogether this can be done in a single dict comprehension:

```
d1 = {'AES': [256], 'Blowfish': [224, 448]} 
d2 = {'AES': [128, 192, 256], 'Blowfish': [112, 224, 448], 'DES': [56]}

{k: list(set(d1[k]).intersection(d2[k])) for k in set(d1) & set(d2)}
# {'AES': [256], 'Blowfish': [224, 448]}
```

Answer (score 2):

This ought to work:

```py
def intersection(obj1, obj2): 
  return list(set(obj1) & set(obj2)) 

d1 = {'AES': [256], 'Blowfish': [224, 448]}
d2 = {'AES': [128, 192, 256], 'Blowfish': [112, 224, 448], 'DES': [56]}

d3 = {key:intersection(d1[key], d2[key]) for key in intersection(d1, d2)}

# write results to file

with open('results.txt','w') as w:
  lst = []
  for key in d3:
    for item in d3[key]:
      lst.append((key, item))
  print('\n'.join(map(str, lst)), file=w)
```

Output (in file "results.txt"):

```
('AES', 256)
('Blowfish', 224)
('Blowfish', 448)
```

Comment: This breaks if you change the order of the dicts (i.e. if d1 is the one with more keys).

Comment: @MarkMeyer I saw the problem. It's fixed :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood the question. You want a list of tuples (str,int) of the intersection? 
if yes I wrote a function:

```
def list_intersection(dict1, dict2):
    return [(name,num)  for name in dict1 for num in dict1[name] if name in dict2 and num in dict2[name]]
```

using this

```
d1 = {'AES': [256], 'Blowfish': [224, 448]}
d2 = {'AES': [128, 192, 256], 'Blowfish': [112, 224, 448], 'DES': [56]} 
print(list_intersection(d1,d2))
```

the printed values is this:

```
[('AES', 256), ('Blowfish', 224), ('Blowfish', 448)]
```